# How do I display data from two different mysql tables in a good way?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which holds the tables:

fish (values are name, image, information, cooking_type_id) and 
cooking_type (values are cooking_type_id, thumbnail)

I've created a very simple mysqli query to display the data from the first table, but I want to display the thumbnail according to the id.

So for cooking_type maybe "Grill" has a cooking_type_id of 1. The fish "Cod" is suitable for grilling therefor it holds the value 1 under "type_id".

Instead of the displaying the "1" how do I display the thumbnail?

Here's my query code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `fish`";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
        echo '<div class="row" style="background-color:#fff;">';

        echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';
        echo '<div class="listphoto">';
        echo $row['image'];
        echo '</div></div>';

        echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';
        echo '<div class="listtext"><h3>';
        echo $row['name'];
        echo '</h3></div></div>';

        echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';
        echo '<div class="typephoto">';
        echo $row['type_id'];
        echo '</div></div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: You can use inner join on cooking_type_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT fish.image, fish.name, cooking_type.thumbnail FROM fish
          JOIN cooking_type
          ON fish.cooking_type_id = cooking_type.cooking_type_id;";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
        echo '<div class="row" style="background-color:#fff;">';

        echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';
        echo '<div class="listphoto">';
        echo $row['image'];
        echo '</div></div>';

        echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';
        echo '<div class="listtext"><h3>';
        echo $row['name'];
        echo '</h3></div></div>';

        echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';
        echo '<div class="typephoto">';
        echo $row['thumbnail'];
        echo '</div></div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Are you sure that array keys will include table prefixes? I think that it should be `$row['image']` not `$row['fish.image']` and so on, but I base it on pdo_pgsql.

Comment: The problem I have here is that name is assigned to both `fish` and `cooking_type`. But I solved this by changing the names to f.name and ctype.name.

Comment: @MstrQKN You can use column aliases ex. `select fish.name as fish_name, cooking_type.name as cooking_type_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JOIN SQL feature :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `fish` 
INNER JOIN `cooking_type` 
    ON `cooking_type`.`cooking_type_id` = `fish`.`cooking_type_id`
```

Doc: [MySQL JOIN SYNTAX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select f.*, ct.* from `fish` as f
left join `cooking_type` as ct
on f.cooking_type_id = ct.cooking_type_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "INNER JOIN" would solve your problem easily :

```
 Select * from fish 

 inner join 'cooking_type' on ............etc, etc
```

[MYSQL INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)